# Plugin in Firefox JavaScript - Link native application with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a plugin for Firefox +57 using WebExtension.
This plugin communicates with a native .exe application, with which I have opened a single port with which I perform the complement-appNative communication.
Simplifying, the complement performs a basic authentication which uses listener and promises.
The question is: how do I communicate the listeners of my native App with the basic authentication listeners through promises. We'll see it better with code:

```
var port;
try {
   port = browser.runtime.connectNative("myAPP");
   port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
} catch(err) {
   Console.log(err.message);
}  

 //Native message listener
function onNativeMessage(message) {
 .
 .more code
 .
  else if (message.response == "basicAuthentication") {
    processBasicAuth(message.data);
  }

}
function basicAuthListener(requestDetails) {
    //*
    //HERE GOES CODE TO PREPARE MY PETITION TO THE NATIVE APP
    // WHOSE ANSWER I WILL COLLECT IN THE LISTENER METHOD processBasicAuth
    */
    var request;

    //prepare request through requestDetails and send

    port.postMessage(request);

    if (pendingRequests.indexOf(requestDetails.requestId) != -1) {

        //retun a PROMISE with cancel

    } else {
        pendingRequests.push(requestDetails.requestId);             
        // return a PROMISE with credentials        
    }
}

function processBasicAuth(message) {

    if(message.action == "ok" ) {
        //Resolve a PROMISE with:           
        /*{
            authCredentials: {
                username: message.username, 
                password: message.password
            }
        }*/ 
    }else{
        // Resolve a PROMISE with "{cancel : true}"         
    }
}   

function completed(requestDetails) {
    var index = pendingRequests.indexOf(requestDetails.requestId);
    if (index > -1) {
    pendingRequests.splice(index, 1); 
    }   
}

browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(basicAuthListener, filter, extraInfoSpec);
browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( completed, filter);
browser.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener( completed,filter);

//end code
```

Thank you very much for your help and from today I start my adventure actively in this community.